# Question on oData and Lightning Connect

Tags: rest-api

We have an urgent requirement where we have to import large set of data in SFDC coming out of an external system (Business Object) on a regular basis. BO will provide a CSV on a daily basis and post to a server location. We have to import this CSV to SFDC. We understand that probably SFDC Bulk api is a good choice here but want to explore other options too. We heard about Lightning connect recently. Now it seems SFDC Lightning connect can be used with oData to show (and not replicate) data in sfdc. Basically using external objects in SFDC we can display external data (from the sources which supports oData) but not replicate that data in sfdc. Is this information correct? Will Lightning connect not work here? Is bulk API is the best option here?

Thanks

Comment: First consider if your situation matches the recommended use where 1) You have a large amount of data that you don’t want to copy into your Salesforce org; 2) You need small amounts of data at any one time; 3) You want real-time access to the latest data. If you have a match, then check your specific external system table(s) against the various [Considerations for Salesforce Connect](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=platform_connect_considerations.htm&language=en_US) and also consider its additional cost.